# Как сделать комментарий в haml?

Tags: haml

Как правильно сделать комментарий в haml ? При "-#" в строке прерывается [конвертация haml в html](https://haml2erb.org/) и не видит вложенных таблиц:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Заголовок
  %body
    %table
    -# Table 1- Main
      %tr
        %td
          %table
          -# Table 2 
            %tr
              %td 1
              %td 2
      %tr
        %td
          %table
          -# Table 3 
            %tr
              %td 3
              %td 4
```

Тоже происходит и при использовании gem haml-rails в Ruby on Rails, что я использую.Подскажите, что я сделал не так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-# Table 1- Main
```

надо просто заменить на

```
/ Table 1- Main
```

Однако следует заметить что это закомментирует всю таблицу. Чтобы исключить это надо просто поменять строки местами:

```
/ Table 1- Main
%table
```

И на выходе мы получим:

```
 <!-- Table 1- Main
    -->
    <table>
```

Вот еще хороший пример с комментированием в haml:

```
- @foo = 42
#test1
  /
    Hello #{@foo}
#test2
  <!-- Hello #{@foo} -->
```

На выходе:

```
<div id='test1'>
  <!--
    Hello 42
  -->
</div>
<div id='test2'>
  <!-- Hello 42 -->
</div>
```

Comment: а есть ли способ не выводить комментарий в html, оставляя его в файле с haml?

Comment: Ну вот этот значок -# это внутренний комментарий, просто вам нужно скорее всего отступы убрать, либо тот веб интерфейс что вы используйте их не поддерживает почему-то или они до него не доходят

Comment: я увидел из-за чего это: из-за того, что есть лишние отступы. Отступ комментария "-#", который сверху, не должен быть больше и меньше отступов следующей строки.

Answer (score 0):

Я увидел из-за чего это: из-за того, что есть лишние отступы. Отступ комментария "-#", который сверху, не должен быть больше и меньше отступов следующей строки.

Примеры когда "-#" не срабатывает:

```
%body
-# Table 1- Main    */ -2 пробела */
  %table
    %tr
```

и

```
%body
   -# Table 1- Main */1 пробел лишний*/
  %table
    %tr
```

правильно:

```
%body
  -# Table 1- Main
  %table
    %tr
```